# How to add a stopwatch timer when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a simple GUI program in java where when I click the Start button, the stopwatch should begin in a JLabel I created. I tried using Timer Swing but it only displays the real time in "HH:mm:ss" in the label which is not what I want.

Is there any function that implement the stopwatch rather than displaying real time timer?

Below is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class GuiStopwatch {





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stopwatch");

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();

          panel.setLayout(null);

          JButton Startbtn = new JButton("START");  
          JButton Stopbtn = new JButton("STOP");
          JButton Reset = new JButton("RESET");
          JLabel time = new JLabel("Time shows here");
             panel.add(Startbtn);
             panel.add(Stopbtn);
            panel.add(Reset);
            panel.add(time);
             Startbtn.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 35);
             Stopbtn.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 35);
             Reset.setBounds(50, 250, 100, 35);
             time.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 35);
             time.setBackground(Color.black);
             time.setForeground(Color.red);
             frame.add(panel);


             Startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Timer timer = new Timer(1,new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                            time.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date()));
                        }
                    });
                timer.start();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `java.time` api to store the Instant of the click and the duration between now and click, like this:

Startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
        Instant start;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            start = Instant.now();

            Timer timer = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    time.setText(Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).getSeconds() + "");
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    });
```

Relevant part is `Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).getSeconds()`.
You can also use getHours, getNanos, getMillis, etc to format your string, for example:

```
duration.getHours() + ":" + duration.getSeconds() + ":" + duration.getNanos();
```

You can also get more information here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Comment: Does this mean it will start from 0:0:0 and keep counting?

Comment: One thing from your solution is it does work but everytime I click the start button again, it restarts everything.

Comment: There doesn't seem be an option for duration.getHours()

Comment: Hi, I thought this was the desired behavior. You can just remove the line `start = Instant.now();` and then it won't reset it.

Comment: Regarding the getHours and 0:0:0, you can also use the following: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss").format(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(duration));`

Comment: What do you mean DateTimeFormatte? Right now, my stopwatch is in "seconds:nanosec" .

Comment: You can't remove start = Instant.now , otherwise it will throw an error

Comment: True, then you also have to change `Instant start;` to `Instant start = Instant.now();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171254/discussion-between-lord-jesus-and-guilherme-mussi).

Answer (score 0):

When you start your timer instantiate a

```
Date beginnig = new Date();
```

Then, when you paint your label instead of

```
time.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date()));
```

write someting like

```
Date current = new Date();
time.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date(current.getTime()-beginning.getTime())));
```

it may be a bit crude but it should work.

Comment: Does this mean it will start from 0:0:0 and keep counting?

Comment: it should. (as long as you do not overwrite `beginning`). I have not tried it though, just telling you how I would code it without spending much time using extra data structures.

Comment: I think the solution posted by another user is more sensible since it does use the proper time API from java to add the seconds